# How to configure MVC config file for to have no caching

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, caching

I am trying to figure out how to configure a ASP.NET MVC2 config file to have absolutely no caching.  My current config file has this xml node...

```
<caching>
  <outputCacheSettings>
    <outputCacheProfiles>
      <add name="ZeroCacheProfile" duration="0" varyByParam="*" location="None" />
    </outputCacheProfiles>
  </outputCacheSettings>
</caching>
```

That would indicate to me, that no caching is going on with with this application.  Am I missing something?  Will continue to browse the internet searching for the most succinct answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining a cache profile in web.config per se doesn't do anything useful other than defining a cache profile. There must be something using this cache profile otherwise it stays a simple definition. So that's half of the job.

The second half is to decorate all your controllers or actions that you would like to disable caching for with the [`[OutputCache]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "ZeroCacheProfile")]
```

or if you want to do this for all controllers of your site define a base controller that all your controllers derive from and then decorate this base controller with the aforementioned attribute.